# tensor integration in spherical coordinate

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, tensors

For a second rank tensor $$T_{ij}=\int_{r=a}(R_i-r_i)(R_j-r_j)|\vec{R}-\vec{r}|^{2p-2}dS(\vec{r})$$ where $p>-1$, and the integral is done over the sphere of radius $a$.

show that $$R_iT_{ij}(\vec{R})R_j=\frac{\pi a^2(2a)^{2p+2}}{p+2}$$
Therefore find the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$$T_{ij}=\alpha\delta_{ij}+\beta R_iR_j$$

Comment: Could you explain what $\vec R$ means in this context? Is it an arbitrary vector? $|\vec R|=1$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, $\vec{R}$ is a fixed vector with magnitude of $a$

Comment: The algorithm is clear. $T_{ij}=\alpha\delta_{ij}+\beta R_iR_j$. Then you get two equations (denoting $a^2=R_iR_i$):
$$1. \qquad T_{ij}\delta_{ij}=\alpha\delta_{ij}\delta_{ij}+\beta R_iR_j\delta_{ij}=3\alpha+a^2\beta$$
$$2. \qquad T_{ij}R_iR_j=\alpha R_iR_i+\beta R_iR_jR_iR_J=\alpha a^2+\beta a^4$$

Comment: Sorry, corrected typos:
On the other hand, choosing the polar axis along the vector $\vec r$ , we get, for example for 1.
$$T_{ij}\delta_{ij}=\int(\vec R −\vec r )^2((\vec R −\vec r )^2)^{p-1}dS=a^{2p}2\pi\int_0^\pi(2−2\cosθ)^{2p}\sinθdθ
=2\pi a^{2p}2^{2p}\int_{-1}^1(1−x)^{2p}dx$$ In the same way you deal with the equation 2.

Comment: Thanks again, is there any recommendation for books that deals with similar problems

Comment: I don't know any. I studied this topic long ago, and it was physics, not math.

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question why $T_{ij}$ must have the form of $T_{ij}=\alpha\delta_{ij}+\beta R_iR_j$

Comment: You simply do not have other options: your tensor is symmetric, and you only have the vector $\vec R$ and tensor $\delta_{ik}$ to construct it.

Comment: that's beautiful much appreciated

Comment: sorry will $T_{ij}R_iR_j=R_iT_{ij}R_j$

Comment: yes, it is correct